# MIST MULTISIG WALLET

Tags: mist, multisignature

I deployed a MULTISIG WALLET with 3 signatories.  It has 3 approvers and I need to update one of the approver's ETH wallet.

Am I able to remove/add signatories using Multisig MIST Wallet???